# Add table row with jquery after two for loops

Tags: php, jquery

Normally I specify the wanted element by eq() function from `jQuery`.

Now I need to specify a table row within two for loops but I can't access to `$i` and `$l`.

This is the code.

```
$content_count   = count($content);
$languages_count = count($languages);
for ($i = 0; $i < $content_count; $i++) {
  for ($l = 0; $l < $languages_count; $l++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <td class="dataTableConfig col-left" style="border-right:1px solid #a3a3a3;">' . $lang_img . TEXT_TITLE . '</td>';
    echo '  <td class="dataTableConfig col-single-right">';
    echo      xtc_draw_input_field('content_title[' . $i . '][' . $languages[$l]['id'] . ']', ((isset($content_lang['content_title'])) ? $content_lang['content_title'] : ''), 'size="60"');
    echo '  </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
```

I tried it whith this code

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '  <td class="dataTableConfig col-left" style="border-right:1px solid #a3a3a3;">' . $lang_img . TEXT_MASK_ALIAS . '</td>';
echo '  <td class="dataTableConfig col-single-right">';
echo      xtc_draw_input_field('mask_alias[' . $i . ']['. $languages[$l]['id'] . ']', ((isset($content_lang['mask_alias'])) ? $content_lang['mask_alias'] : ''), 'size="60"');
echo '  </td>';
echo '</tr>';
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content   = <?php echo $content_count; ?>;
  var languages = <?php echo count($languages); ?>;
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < languages.length; l++) {
      $("[name^='mask_alias']").closest("tr").detach().insertAfter($("[name=^'content_title']").closest("tr"));    
    }  
  }
});  
</script>
```

But it's not at the right place and the counts of $i and $l are wrong.

Comment: does your console display any errors? Not sure why exactly you'd not be able to access variables, within their own loops. Unless they override some globals, possibly? Have you tried defining them with `var i = 0...`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The code you've posted is entirely PHP and no jQuery, yet you've only tagged and mentioned jQuery. Your post doesn't ask a question, nor is it clear at all what you're trying to achieve. Please edit it to provide more detail, explain what you're trying to achieve, what you've already attempted, and most importantly - ask an actual question!

Comment: I think you have to add them a `.class` then access them via the jquery selector

Comment: I added some more information for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content   = <?php echo $content_count; ?>;
  var languages = <?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>;
  var row       = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < content; i++) {
     $.each(languages, function(key, value) {
      row  = '<tr>';
      row += '  <td class="dataTableConfig col-left" style="border-right:1px solid #a3a3a3;">';
      row += '    <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">';
      row += '      <img src="/lang/' + value['directory'] + '/admin/images/' + value['image'] + '" alt="' + value['name'] + '" title="' + value['name'] + '" style="border:0;">';
      row += '    </div>';
      row += '     <?php echo TEXT_MASK_ALIAS; ?>';
      row += '  </td>';
      row += '  <td class="dataTableConfig col-single-right">';
      row += '    <input type="text" name="mask_alias[' + i + '][' + value['id'] + ']" value="<?php echo (isset($content_lang['mask_alias']) ? $content_lang['mask_alias'] : ''); ?>" size="60">';
      row += '  </td>';
      row += '</tr>';
      $('[name="content_title[' + i + '][' + value['id'] + ']').closest('tr').after(row);
    });  
  } 
});  
</script>
```